# How to add a gradient to a JScrollPane's viewport?

Tags: java, swing, gradient, jscrollpane, viewport

I've seen how to add a gradient by having a class extend a component, override the `paintComponent` method, and then write code to add a gradient and bam there it is.

But I have a `JScrollPane` with a `JTable` on the viewport. I'm adding rows and columns as needed, and I want a gradient for the background, until the rows cover it up.

Getting the viewport and setting the color works great: I just want it be a gradient.

```
scrollPane.getViewport().setBackground(Color.blue);
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Can't you set a custom viewport that extends the default class and paints the gradient as you already know how?

Comment: I'm just making a guess here, which may or may not be correct, but it sounds like you might want to do `#setViewport(...)` with a JPanel of your own, that has `JPanel#setOpaque(true)` with an overriden `#paintComponent(Graphics)` where you draw with an increasing/decreasing alpha value as you move up/down the panel.

Comment: @search. Almost, except it has to be a JViewPort

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than getting the existing viewport, you need to *set* a custom one. In particular, extend [`JViewport`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JViewport.html) to draw a gradient in exactly the same manner you would with any other `JComponent`. Then call [`setViewport()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JScrollPane.html#setViewport-javax.swing.JViewport-) on your `JScrollPane` with an instance of your new class as the argument.